# Plotting k-means output - python

Tags: machine-learning, python, visualization, k-means

Can anyone help with plotting k-means results from GraphLab k-means tool.

```
sf = gl.SFrame(df_only_tags)
K = int(sqrt(sf.num_rows() / 2.0))

kmeans_model = gl.kmeans.create(sf, num_clusters=6)
kmeans_model.summary()

print(kmeans_model['cluster_info'][['cluster_id', 'size', 'sum_squared_distance']])
print(kmeans_model['cluster_id'].head())
kmeans_model.show()
```

I am able to print my results just fine, but looking for the best way to represent my results visually:

```
+------------+-------+----------------------+
| cluster_id |  size | sum_squared_distance |
+------------+-------+----------------------+
|     0      | 10594 |     1034.9124542     |
|     1      |  312  |    42.9715532884     |
|     2      |   2   |    84.9999923706     |
|     3      |   1   |         0.0          |
|     4      |   98  |    213.489804491     |
|     5      |   1   |         0.0          |
+------------+-------+----------------------+
[6 rows x 3 columns]

+--------+------------+-----------------+
| row_id | cluster_id |     distance    |
+--------+------------+-----------------+
|   0    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   1    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   2    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   3    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   4    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   5    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   6    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   7    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   8    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
|   9    |     0      | 0.0553383231163 |
+--------+------------+-----------------+
[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

as always, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If the dim of your data is more than 2, you may want to transform your data with PCA, t-SNE or Custom linear projections.

t-SNE is recommended for clustering result.

For example:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
data = tsne.fit_transform(data)
```

This may lose some information, but useful for visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, I'd follow the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881994/matplotlib-how-to-change-data-points-color-based-on-some-variable).

In your case, you'll be setting the point colors based on the cluster ID.

However, the cluster sizes are so imbalanced that it could be hard to see anything except for cluster 0. Since all of the distances in the header are identical, perhaps you're modeling duplicate points? If you can drop the duplicates before plotting the chart will probably be easier to read. Alternately, you could scale the point sizes by the number of duplicates.

Comment: so are row_id and distance the x, y values respectively?

Comment: You'd probably want the actual features as X & Y. For example, let's say your data set was about countries and contained population, GDP, land area, etc as features. You could use population and GDP as your X and Y. The user would be able to see the distances for those dimensions. [This section of the Seaborn docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) has a nice example. Search for "Show different levels of a categorical variable by the color of plot elements" within that page for the relevant image.